# checkbox text (inside a checkedlistbox) wont appear

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkbox, checkedlistbox

i've added a checkbox to a checkedlistbox using the following code:

```
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
        cb.Enabled = false;
        cb.Text = "A B C D";
        checkedListBox1.Items.Add(cb);
```

but, as seen in the picture, the text wont show up. what have I done wrong ?
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only add text and not a `CheckBox` control. The [CheckedListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.aspx) control will create the check boxes itself:

```
checkedListBox1.Items.Add("A B C D");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add a `CheckBox` control to the `CheckedListBox`. Just add text (`Item`).

```
   checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(new String[]{"A","B","C"});
```

Hope this helps.